Can one execute a function in background from a function that is already running in background?
Considering the following script:
if [[ -z "$DOWNLOAD_ONLY" || "$DOWNLOAD_ONLY" = *conditions* ]]; then
  function get_condition {
    curl -s "https://conditions.com" | jq '.included[].attributes | select(retracted)' | jq --arg item $2 '. + {item: $item}' > "$1_$2.json"
  }

  function conditions {
    for item in `cat items.json | jq -r '.data[].id'`
    do
      get_condition $1 $item
    done

    jq -s '.' $1_*.json | jq 'reduce .[] as $item (retracted)' > "$1.json"

    rm $1_*.json
  }

  curl "https://items.com" | jq '.' > "items.json"

  for language in cs da de en es fr it nl pl pt sv zh
  do
    conditions $language &
  done

  wait
fi

Can I add & to get_condition $1 $item and then call wait afterwards?

This is a somewhat interesting question, but the example code is really distracting.  (1) The entire code block is enclosed in an if-then block that adds nothing.  (2) function a is called with parameters, but it doesn’t take any.  (3) The $(…) syntax is preferred over \…`.  (4) You should always quote shell variables (e.g., a "$1" "$n") unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  (5) It’s very confusing that you have functions called a and b, but you also use a and b (and c`) as data strings.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', sorry about that. I tried to obfuscate the code from the company where I work. I'll try to improve it later.

For some reason, the example in real life is crashing. The response from curl is piped to jq, and the jq can't parse it. I need to check what curl is returning in such cases.

I've improved the snippet.

I imagine a concern could be that waiting in b would wait for all processes started from the shell script, leading to a deadlock. That’s not a problem, wait waits for children of the current (sub)shell; running b in the background forces it to have its own subshell, with its own list of jobs and child processes.
So
  function b {
    for n in `cat ok.txt`
    do
      a $1 $n &
    done
    wait
  }

will work fine as far as that’s concerned — b will wait for the as it started, and only those.
